# to isolate commands and values read in a single line

Tags: python

I created a list in python:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I ask the user to input a command from in a single line.
e.g. **append 6**

Is there a way other than separating the function "append' and the value '6' to carry this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split%20%60str.split%60):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

user_input = raw_input('next action:') # e.g. append 6
action = append_input.split()
```

Now we have `action = ['append', '6']`.

Answer (score 0):

Jumm a alternative for append could be this, but dont like it:

```
a= [1,2]
b = int(raw_input('give me the number'))
a= a+[b]
print a
```

or maybe use the insert() function

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
function, value = input('command: ').split()
if function == 'append': a.append(int(value))
```